I want to clone pancakeSwap V3-core-contracts. i need deployment step to run pancakeSwap clone succcessfully. github deployments not working properly
Add Key in .env file. It's a private key of the account that will deploy the contracts and should be gitignored.
bscTestnet KEY_TESTNET or bsc KEY_MAINNET
add ETHERSCAN_API_KEY in .env file. It's an API key for etherscan.
yarn in root directory
NETWORK=$NETWORK yarn zx v3-deploy.mjs where $NETWORK is either eth, goerli, bscMainnet, bscTestnet or hardhat (for local testing)
NETWORK=$NETWORK yarn zx v3-verify.mjs where $NETWORK is either eth, goerli, bscMainnet, bscTestnet or hardhat (for local testing)

I guess you are passing the wrong values in the .env file

Copy variables for .env variables from .env.example

KEY_TESTNET=
KEY_MAINNET=
KEY_ETH=
KEY_GOERLI=
ETHERSCAN_API_KEY=


Paste those variables in the .env file

Define KEY_TESTNET= <your_wallet_account_private_key>
You can remove or comment out other KEY variables these variables only denote your wallet account's private key
Create an account on any block explorer you want to use go to your profile there on the left-hand side under the other section you'll find the API Keys section there click on +Add and name your project it'll create API key for you after that assign that key to ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
Add new variable as NETWORK = <network_name> where network name can be eth, goerli, bscMainnet, bscTestnet, or hardhat
And the last step would be to go to your terminal and paste the below command
NETWORK=$NETWORK yarn zx v3-deploy.mjs where $NETWORK is either eth, goerli, bscMainnet, bscTestnet or hardhat (for local testing)
In the same way, you can verify your contract and replace v3-deploy.mjs with v3-verify.mjs

I did it , but got error

What is the error that you are facing? - @user135270

Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

Invalid account: #0 for network: bscMainnet - private key too long, expected 32 bytes

private key is correct

Basically whatever the private key you are providing is not correct please check the private key you are passing @user135270
